# Is k-means++ meant to be perfect every time? What other initialization strategies can yield the best k-means?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

I've implemented a k-means algorithm and performance is highly dependent on how centroids were initialized. I'm finding random uniform initialization to give a good k-means about 5% of the time, whereas with k-means++, it's closer to 50%. Why is the yield for good k-means so low? I should disclaim I've only used a handful of data sets and my good/bad rates are indicative of only those, not broadly.

Here's an example using k-means++ where the end result was not great. The Dunn Index of this clustering is 0.16.

[image]

And an example where it worked perfectly with a Dunn Index of 0.67.

[image]

I was maybe under the naive impression k-means++ produced a good k-means every time. Is there perhaps something wrong with my code?

```py
def initialize_centroids(points, k):
    """
    Parameters:
        points : a list of Points.
        k : how many centroids to place.
    
    Returns:
        A list of centroids.
    """
    clusters = []
    clusters.append(choice(points)) # first centroid is random point
    for _ in range(k - 1): # for other centroids
        distances = []
        for p in points:
            d = inf
            for c in clusters: # find the minimal distance between p and c
                d = min(d, distance(p, c))
            distances.append(d)
        # find maximum distance index from minimal distances
        clusters.append(points[distances.index(max(distances))])
    return clusters
```

This is adapted from the algorithm as found on Wikipedia:

> Choose one center uniformly at random from among the data points.
>
> For each data point x, compute D(x), the distance between x and the nearest center that has already been chosen.
>
> Choose one new data point at random as a new center, using a weighted probability distribution where a point x is chosen with probability proportional to D(x)2.
>
> Repeat Steps 2 and 3 until k centers have been chosen.
>
> Now that the initial centers have been chosen, proceed using standard k-means clustering.

The difference is the centroids are chosen such that it is the furthest distance, not a probability to choose between furthest distances.

My intention is to compare the Dunn Index over different values of `k`, and empirically the Dunn Index being higher means better clustering. I can't collect (good) data if half of the time it doesn't work, so my results are skewed due to the faultiness of k-means++ or my implementation thereof.

What other initialization strategies can be employed to get a more consistent result?

Comment: Your first paragraph mentions `k-means` and `k-means++`.  Are you comparing these two methods or are you talking about `k-means++` all the time?

Comment: @Gabriel I'm under the impression k-means is the clustering algorithm and k-means++ is the initialization strategy. I'm using both for the entirety of my question.

Comment: Oh I see. So you are basically wondering why your `k-means++` implementation "fails" at the observed rate. I believe a good sanity check would be to compare your implementation with `scikit-learn` [KMeans](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html). It uses the `k-means++` method by default and if that (well tested) implementation has a similar performance to yours, then that's as good as it gets.

Comment: The [`scipy.cluster.KMeans`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) implementation uses 10 different seed initializations by default, so this suggest they expect a "good" result 10% of the time on average (at minimum). You should definitely compare your method to theirs.